# How to fix the error 'member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union'

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently programming a game of tic tac toe and I am trying to give the player the option to replay the game when it is done.

I am using a structure for this but I keeping getting error messages similar to " *error: member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union 
grid[gridsize][gridsize] = make_move(ReplayX.X[sequence_number], ReplayX.Y[sequence_number], ReplayX.player);*"

the grid declaration

```
 #define MaxGrid 10
 char grid[MaxGrid][MaxGrid];
```

the struct code...

```
   typedef struct Move replay_move(int sequence_number)
 {
     char player;

     int X[sequence_number];
     int Y[sequence_number];

  }ReplayX, ReplayO;
```

the replay code...

```
  while (answer != n)
    {
        ReplayX.player = 'X';
        ReplayO.player = 'O';

        grid[gridsize][gridsize] = make_move(ReplayX.X[sequence_number], ReplayX.Y[sequence_number], ReplayX.player);

        printf("Next or Exit (n,e)?");
        scanf("%c",&answer);

        gameProgress = player_won (ReplayX.player);

        sequence_number++;

        grid[gridsize][gridsize] = make_move(ReplayO.X[sequence_number], ReplayO.Y[sequence_number], ReplayO.player);

        printf("Next or Exit (n,e)?");
        scanf("%c",&answer);
        sequence_number++;

        gameProgress = player_won (ReplayO.player);


    }
}
```

The game can be played on a grid from 3 to 10 so grid[gridsize][gridsize] is a 2d array that stores the X or O.

MakeMove is a function that changes the character in the grid at from '.' to the letter X or O.

Comment: `grid[gridsize][gridsize] = make_move(ReplayX.X[sequence_number], ReplayX.Y[sequence_number], ReplayX.player);` is suspicious,  What is `gridsize`, `make_move()`.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: Your `typedef` won't even compile because it contains a function declaration [that is probably wrong/unwanted]. Also, [given that you're doing tic-tac-toe], `gridsize` is probably 3. So, `grid[gridsize][gridsize]` is [probably] going beyond the bounds of the array.